# Power BI getting measures on the same timeline

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset where I have cases every day for the past 2 years. I have a date column, Case Number, and Service Pack. Service packs are released every 6 months. So data for SP1 starts from jan1, data for SP2 starts from July 1. I want to compare the count of cases for each different service back together. Example SP 1 and SP2 on the same timeframe showing me comparison on a weekly basis. Like W1 Sp1 count, Sp2 count, and so forth. Attached image for reference. I can quickly do this in excel but want to create this in Power BI.

W1 would be data for the first week of Jan for Sp1, Similarly, W1 for Sp2 would be data for 1st week of July. I want to show both on the same axis like the image attached.

```
Case     Date        SP's
1      01/01/2020    SP1
1      02/01/2020    SP1
1      03/01/2020    SP1
1      04/01/2020    SP1
1      05/01/2020    SP1
1      06/01/2020    SP1
1      07/01/2020    SP1
1      08/01/2020    SP1
1      09/01/2020    SP1
1      10/01/2020    SP1
1      11/01/2020    SP1
1      12/01/2020    SP1
1      13/01/2020    SP1
1      14/01/2020    SP1
1      15/01/2020    SP2
1      16/01/2020    SP2
1      17/01/2020    SP2
1      18/01/2020    SP2
1      19/01/2020    SP2
1      20/01/2020    SP2
1      21/01/2020    SP2
```

Data Sample: [image]

[image]

Comment: And where is the data you aggregated in the columns?

Comment: It's a count of case numbers. So for this sample data, it would be, in the x-axis: 
Week 1 count of all the Cases then split by the legend, which is the service pack.

Comment: The only thing which I'm not able to do is get them on the same graph. As week 1 for SP1 will start from 1st Jan, and for SP2 week1 will be from July 1. As explained in the question. I don't know how to get them together. And show it like the image attached.